# Is there any way to trace all exceptions in WCF?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, exception, trace

How can I enable tracing of any exceptions (doesn't matter was it handled or unhandled) in WCF? Here is the code that I has configured:

```
<system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Error,ActivityTracing"
        propagateActivity="true">
        <listeners>
          <add type="System.Diagnostics.DefaultTraceListener" name="Default">
            <filter type="" />
          </add>
          <add name="ServiceModelTraceListener">
            <filter type="" />
          </add>
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
    <sharedListeners>
      <add initializeData="tracelog.svclog"
        type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
        name="ServiceModelTraceListener" traceOutputOptions="DateTime, Timestamp, Callstack">
        <filter type="" />
      </add>
    </sharedListeners>
  </system.diagnostics>
```

But then I try to see any exceptions in SvcTraceViewer I don't see exceptions. How can I get exceptions in trace log?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: "doesn't matter was it handled ..." - what do you mean by this?  Obviously if an exception is handled in the implementation of an OperationContract, it will never by seen by the WCF infrastructure so couldn't possibly be logged by WCF.

Comment: I meant that exceptions that was handled in `try {} catch {}` blocks.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see an obvious problem in your config, but this is what I use, and I do see exceptions in Svc Trace Viewer:

```
    <system.diagnostics>
        <sources>
            <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing" propagateActivity="true">
                <listeners>
                    <add name="XTL" />
                </listeners>
            </source>
        </sources>
        <sharedListeners>
            <add initializeData="trace.svclog" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" name="XTL" />
        </sharedListeners>
        <trace autoflush="true" />
    </system.diagnostics>
```

Comment: Could you please point me at the place in SvcTraceViewer where you can see exceptions?

Comment: @kseen - In the Activity View, you should see red-colored items in the list. Once you click on one of them, the right panels will display specific traces, including again red-colored ones, that represent the exception, with details and stack frame.

Comment: not working for exception custom behaviorExtensions ?